# aligning images

Tags: html, css

What's the best way to align images ina list. I am trying something like and I expect them to see aligned vertifically below each other but the text kinda wraps aorund the image.

- text
- image
- text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just using float left, and it's work
the code will like this

HTML:

- text here

```
<li>
   <img src="" />
    text here
</li>
</ul>
```

and for CSS:

```
li img {float:left; vertical-align: top;}
```

sorry for my bad typing, i still learning how to typing code here..

if the code still unclear please inform me, i will upload my full code to my host.

if give vertical align to make the bullet numbering goes to upper of the image

Answer (score 0):

To remove text, put all text in floating elements and put `clear: both` in images. With this, the text will not wrap image.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but it sounds like you're using floats. There's no need.

CSS:

```
#mylist li{ display: block }
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="myLst">
  <li>text</li>
  <li><img src="my-image.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

That will align each List Item on top of one another.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use Foundation or Bootstrap with their grids. Then you can align images and text in a row using columns. But the quick and simple solution would be to use:

`img{display:block;}`